# Calling anonymous functions in Python without assigning them to a variable

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

How to make *Self-Invoking Anonymous Functions* in Python?

For example with JavaScript:

*Standard way:*

```
function fn (a) {
   if (a == 1) {
      alert(a);
   }
   else {
     alert(0);
   }
  /...
}

fn(1);
```

Self-Invoking Anonymous call:

```
!function(a) {
   if (a == 1) {
      alert(a);
   }
   else {
     alert(0);
   }
   /...
}(1);
```

Are there any analogues in Python?

Comment: @Marcin, just wondering)

Comment: That first case is not anonymous. Neither of them are "self-invoking" in any sense. I edited the title.

Comment: @Opsa: "just wondering" does not make a bad question become magically good.  Please explain what the use case is.

Comment: @S.Lott I suppose that it might make it easier to port JavaScript libraries to Python, since many JavaScript libraries use this pattern.

Comment: In 2017, the main use case I use this for is to prebind/freeze the values of a datastucture (like a `dict`) that is meant to be imported from inside another module without having to assign/define an actual function or explicitly pickle: `STATIC_CONST_D = (lambda S: {x: transform(x) for x in S})(set(1,2,3))` `from module import STATIC_CONST_D`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think is possible, given your comments to the lambda answers. The `lambda` operator is Python's only way of supporting anonymous functions. If you need to support statements, then you need to use a `def`, which always must be named.

Keep in mind that lambdas can support limited if-then logic, however. The following two are `lambda` expressions that implements the if-then logic given above:

```
(lambda a: alert(1 if a == 1 else 0))(1)
```

More literally:

```
(lambda a: alert(a) if a == 1 else alert(0))(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

If your function is simple and only has expressions (no statements), then you can use [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to create anonymous functions and call them inline.

```
>>> (lambda x, y: x*y)(3, 5)
15
```

Comment: I know about `lambda`'s. However, I am interested in the use of `statements` within functions as well

Comment: @Opsa: Python does not have full anonymous functions, to a large extent because there is no usecase for them outside obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (Python 3 or Python 2 using `from __future__ import print_function`):

```
(lambda x: print(x))('foo')
```

But using `lambda` you can only write a single line of code.

Comment: to be precise, you can only use lambda to turn an *expression* into a function.  normal `def`ed functions are permitted to use "lines" of code, what in the python grammar is called a suite.  That's why it's necessary to use the print *function*, because that can be used as part of an expression, where the print *statement* cannot be used that way.

Comment: You can use expressions - not statements. If you want to hack in multiple expressions, you may do that, for example, making the lambda function generate a tuple, each term of which is one expression. Ex.:`lambda a: (thing1(), thing2(), thing3())`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a named function and unbind its name after using it like:

```
def hello(there):
    print there
hello("france")
del hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always abuse `exec`, passing your code as a string:

```
def anon(code):
    execdict = {}
    exec('def f():{}'.format(code), execdict)
    return execdict['f']

anon("print('hello'); print('hello again')")()
```

(this works in python 3, I think `exec` behaves very differently in earlier versions)